# User starting a conversation with another user and a chatbot

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams

Not sure how to approach this.
The flow kind of goes like this:
 1. The client initiates a conversation with the chatbot asking for support.
 2. Eventually the chatbot creates a message such as this[image: custom dialog in chat window] on a team channel where support agents are available. From my understanding I can create links that would open group dialogues like so ? https://teams.microsoft.com/l/chat/0/0?users=user@email.com,user2@email.com or using the id ?

How can I do this for creating a group chat with the user AND the chatbot ? I tried adding it's ID and it didn't work for some reason but adding real users separated by comma worked.

If anything is there a way to use the Graph API to detect if a conversation was started between someone on the channel and the client ?

Comment: To do this in Teams channel, you'd need to "register" your bot via it's App Id, something [like this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/teamsappinstallation-add?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http), but I'm not sure you can do this on group chat, to auto-register the bot. One possible avenue - which ID did you use for the bot? It's AppId or it's Teams Id?

Comment: I used the id obtained from Get bot embed codes for Teams channel in the Bot Channels Registration

Comment: yeah, I think that's the right one